# Android Invalidate doesn't refresh the whole activity

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, invalidation

Here are the components in my activity:

1. A list view
2. Bottom bar which is actually a RelativeLayout under the list view. It's dynamically shown or hidden in my program. Something like this

**Code**

```
if ( condition ) {           
   bottombar.getLayoutParams().height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;               
} else {        
   bottombar.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
}        
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

It seems the invalidate() doesn't work at all. If I add something, I set the height of the bottom bar. The view is not refreshed at all. It will be only refreshed after I scroll my ListView.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you running this code on the main thread?

Comment: By the way, If I add a line before invalidate() like this: listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), it will work. But I don't know why?

Comment: Actually the listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged() only will refresh the view. The invalidate() and requestLayout() won't.

Comment: Can you show some more of where this code is to get a better context of what's going on?

Comment: @codeMagic - The whole application is quite complicated. But the above mentioned code is called inside onActivityResult() which is returned from another activity (also called in onCreate as an initialization). The other activity is started by clicking the cell in the listview.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `invalidate()`, you should call `requestLayout()` after changing the height of the relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);
vg.invalidate();
```

Now, when the Activity resumes, it makes every View to draw itself. No call to invalidate() should be needed. To apply the theme, make sure you do it before any View is drawn, i.e., before `setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);`